# SEO and Having Redirects Mixed with HREFs on Same Page

Tags: javascript, redirect, seo, href

The e-commerce site I'm currently working on has several offices/web sites (Australia, Canada, Europe etc) and we're trying to rework the site to be more compliant with SEO and to up our rankings on Google.  Originally we had a Jquery dialog popup asking the user for their shipping country (via a drop down) and we'd then determine which site the merchandise would be shipped out of and redirect them to the appropriate site folder (http://www.mydomain.com/en-ca etc) via Javascript

We were advised to change this for SEO purposes and list all the countries we ship to by having them wrapped in an href tag and to get rid of the initial dialog box.  Since the change we have had customers accidentally be on the wrong site and launch a complaint when they weren't able to order what they wanted because of the differences in stock on the various sites.

We are now thinking of doing a portal page that'd be a hybrid version of the above solutions.  List our office locations as an simple href and then under that have a “If your country is not listed, select it from the drop down” which will redirect them to the right site via javascript.

My question is, will having that javascript redirect alongside the hrefs harm our SEO?  Will Google's crawler look at the drop down, see a redirect and stop dead it in its tracks and refuse to crawl the rest of the site?

We pretty much ship to anywhere in the world but it's not blatantly obvious which office the merchandise will come out of based on the user's shipping country.  (For example our Canada location is the catch all.  If a person is say from New Zealand, then they should be on our Australia office, but if they're from China, they'd go to our Canadian site.)

All the “sites” are under the same domain but under virtual folders, mydomain.com/en-ca, mydomain.com/en-au and so on as well as sharing the same code.  (Obviously the stock displayed will be different for each and the currency will also change accordingly)

[EDIT] In the top right hand corner of the page in the header, it says the shipping country, which will be the country that the user chooses, not necessarily the site that the user is on.  The purpose of this is so if the user selects China and sees the prices in Canadian dollars, they can see that they are on the correct site from the shipping country that is being display.  We kept track of their selection either by a javascript function to set cookies before redirecting, but later on we changed the code to have each country as an href with a querystring that would eventually set the shipping country cookie to track their selection.

Originally the site was coded to default to Canada, and if a shipping country cookie wasn't set, we would show them a popup asking them to choose.  (We were told by an outside consultant to get rid of this as Google would not be able to crawl the site, though I can't think why that'd be the case)  Since getting rid of that initial popup, we have had several complaints from customer who don't realize they are on the Canadian site by default because now it's not that obvious  (We still have the shipping country displayed, but it's not as in-your-face as the original design with the initial popup).

Comment: why would it need to be a javascript redirect? Btw, you shouldn't start your site with a popup asking the user for personal information.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to redirect with javascript? You can put a list of link tags with an href to the correct site.

You could also use geolocalisation features to attempt to detect the user location.

Another solution, would be to send everyone to the canadian store and when they first arrive open a popup asking for their location. Google Bot would then see the Canadian Store first.

Comment: There are times when they are needed and helpful, but they shouldn't ever be shown on every page. The most obvious example is sites about alcohol that shouldn't be viewed by minors (at least in Canada). Example: http://www.sleeman.ca/

Comment: I just edited my post explaining why I need the Javascript redirect.  Or something similar.